# Какого рода "кеды"?

Tags: морфология

Недавно в кроссворде мне попался вопрос "спортивная обувь" и ответ был "кеда" (в смысле, в единственном числе). Но что-то меня берет сомнение - разве не "кед"? Мне всегда казалось, что в единственном числе это слово мужского рода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, в известных мне словарях - только мужской род.
Хотя что-то мне подсказывает, что женский род, возможно, через какое-то время будет признан хотя бы частично нормативным. Слово действительно испытывает тенденцию к изменению рода. Но в кроссворде, конечно, ненормативные варианты - нонсенс.